# Do you get change from cards in Ascension?

Tags: ascension

Say I have three cards in my hand Ascension, each worth two points.

Am I allowed to buy two cards worth three points each (As I had six total), or can I only buy a three point and a two point card as I've used two cards in my hand to pay for the three-point card?

Put another way, do I get change when I spend the points on a card?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can buy 2 cards costing three runes each, but not because you get "change".

When you play a card worth 2 runes, what that does is adds 2 runes to the pool of runes you have available to spend. So when you play 3 cards like that, you now have 6 runes in the pool of runes to spend. It no longer matters at all how the runes got there. You have 6 runes to spend, and you can spend them however you like.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get change.  And be sure to note the proper terminology and attributes of cards.

The white triangle = runes = money to buy stuff
Red circle = power = strength to kill monsters in the CR (Center Row)
The star = honor = victory points that win you the game.  The plastic gems that come with the game (cardboard tokens in the Apprentice Edition) are also honor added as part of your total score

The top right of the card shows the card's cost to purchase in runes, or to defeat with power (vs. Monsters).

The bottom left (star) shows how much honor you get at the end of the game.

When playing cards that give you runes (like Mystics), they add to your total # of runes to spend.  You do NOT get handed out plastic rune or coin tokens when playing them.  You keep track of them "in your head". If you played 3 Mystics, that's $6 (or runes).  You purchase a $3 card, now you have $3 left.  You may then purchase another $3 card.  You now have $0 left, so you end your turn.